# Passing generic when calling a function and get the type dynamically as the function return type

Tags: javascript, typescript

Could you please check out the following code snippet and point out why the `getStoreForView` function throwing compiling error such as and modify the following code to achieve that if I pass 'emptyViewType' As the generic value then the return type should be '{ viewId: number, data: EmptyViewType}' and when passing in 'invoiceViewType' the data type would be 'InvoiceViewType'

```
Type '{ viewId: number; data: { products: string; billingTriggers: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ViewLocalStorageStore<T>'.
  Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
    Type '{ products: string; billingTriggers: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ViewTypes[T]'.
      Type '{ products: string; billingTriggers: string; }' is not assignable to type 'EmptyViewType & InvoiceViewType'.
        Type '{ products: string; billingTriggers: string; }' is not assignable to type 'EmptyViewType'.
          Property 'products' is incompatible with index signature.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Code:

```
type Product = string
type BillingTrigger = Record<string, unknown>[]

interface ViewLocalStorageStore<T extends keyof ViewTypes> {
    viewId: number;
    data: ViewTypes[T];
}

type ViewTypes = {
  emptyViewType: EmptyViewType;
  invoiceViewType: InvoiceViewType;
};

enum StorageStoreType {
  EmptyViewType = 'emptyViewType',
  InvoiceViewType = 'invoiceViewType',
  FailedViewType = 'failedViewType',
}

type EmptyViewType = Record<string, never>

type InvoiceViewType = {
  products: string;
  billingTriggers: string;
};

const getStoreForView = <T extends keyof ViewTypes>(viewId: number): ViewLocalStorageStore<T> => {
    return {
        viewId,
        data: {
            products: '123123',
            billingTriggers: '123123123'
        }
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
getStoreForView<StorageStoreType.InvoiceViewType>(123)
```

Comment: The `getStoreForView()` function call signature purports to return a value of type `ViewLocalStorageStore<T>` for any `T` the caller wants.  But clearly the return value is not a ViewLocalStorageStore<"emptyViewType">, so the function is not properly implemented.  Does that make sense? If so I can write up an answer explaining it; if not, let me know what's missing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Well. What I want to achieve there is if i pass 'emptyViewType' As the generic value then the return type should Be { viewId: number, data: EmptyViewType} and when passing in invoiceViewType the data type would be InvoiceViewType

Comment: That makes sense but your question does not ask for that, it asks "why is there an error".  Do you want to [edit] the question so that it shows desired inputs and outputs instead of only presenting code that doesn't type check or work?  That is, rephrase the question into a "how can I achieve this" form?

Comment: Once you do this, note that since the TS type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) upon compilation to JS, there's no way to make `getStoreForView<XYZ>(123)` behave differently from `getStoreForView<ABC>(123)`.  Both compile to `getStoreForView(123)`.  If you want different things to happen at runtime, you should pass in different values at runtime; [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NVadZw) is one way to proceed.  If that meets your needs I can write up an answer.

Comment: @jcalz Yeah. I browsed the code a bit and I think that probably suits my need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original version of `getStoreForView()` doesn't work because the call signature claims to be able to return a `ViewLocalStorageStore<K>` for any `K extends keyof ViewTypes` that the caller wants, while its implementation seems to return a `ViewLocalStorageStore<StorageStoreType.InvoiceViewType>` no matter what.  The error

```
Type '{ products: string; billingTriggers: string; }' 
  is not assignable to type 'ViewTypes[K]'
```

is essentially telling you that you are returning an `InvoiceViewType` where the compiler expects a `ViewTypes[K]` for whatever `K` the caller wants.  It can't verify that; indeed, someone can call

```
const oops = getStoreForView<StorageStoreType.EmptyViewType>(456);
// const oops: ViewLocalStorageStore<StorageStoreType.EmptyViewType>
```

and the compiler would need to hand back a `ViewLocalStorageStore<StorageStoreType.EmptyViewType>`, which is not happening.    Hence the error.

---

Instead, you will need to implement the function so that it actually depends on `K` in some way.

Since the TypeScript type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) upon compilation to TypeScript, you can't have `K` appear only in the type parameter; both `getStoreForView<StorageStoreType.InvoiceViewType>(789)` and `getStoreForView<StorageStoreType.EmptyViewType>(789)` will produce the same JavaScript code, namely `getStoreForView(789)`.  So `K` will have to appear in the type for at least one of the function parameters.  For example:

```
const getStoreForView = <K extends keyof ViewTypes>(
    viewType: K,
    viewId: number
): ViewLocalStorageStore<K> => { /* impl */ }
```

I've added an initial `viewType` parameter which must be of type `K`.  Now instead of calling `getStoreForView<StorageStoreType.InvoiceViewType>(789)`, you call `getStoreForView(StorageStoreType.InvoiceViewType, 789)`.  This relatively minor change of syntax has important ramifications for the function implementation.

Here's one way to implement `getStoreForView()` with the new call signature:

```
const storeData: ViewTypes = {
    emptyViewType: {},
    invoiceViewType: { products: '123123', billingTriggers: '123123123' }
}

const getStoreForView = <K extends keyof ViewTypes>(
    viewType: K,
    viewId: number
): ViewLocalStorageStore<K> => {
    return {
        viewId,
        data: storeData[viewType]
    }
}
```

The above compiles successfully.  We've stored a `storeData` value of the `ViewTypes` type which is a mapping from `keyof ViewTypes` keys to a corresponding view type object.  Let's test it out:

```
const eStore = getStoreForView(StorageStoreType.EmptyViewType, 123);
// const eStore: ViewLocalStorageStore<StorageStoreType.EmptyViewType>
console.log(eStore.data) // {}

const iStore = getStoreForView(StorageStoreType.InvoiceViewType, 123);
// const iStore: ViewLocalStorageStore<StorageStoreType.InvoiceViewType>
console.log(iStore.data.products.toUpperCase()) // "123123"
```

Looks good, both at compile time and at runtime!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ssl=19&ssc=6&pln=19&pc=19#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-wfF8RTJD0eYZPCRwISkUBlsKlZFDWDZNiCuoyp27CcD2eH9o2A5QH044ATqnAmtGZpwBaODWragQOmEERRF8iTumC2azFAVooek2Y+sUZT+uQQYujYdjPh+r7JtacYJmCybAKm6aJvmUm5kOBaNGK0ZgY06gifE2ijvRgG+I8PBMUubE5O6L4PF+8TbgCXzSE2Z7kJe14MZg3meBBT7hq4aleF5G6+T+0LshOCD0BAm70AgpDupFyabvUjQBlAoVIToN5QIQzk4K5LHLlYnmqQVTy+dy6HQoFDbBaFVU1dG0XKbFkate+cWtVuHWIpBkBpQxGVZTleUDZ4RWFpu2EVrgm4uAAqmAkBwAAwkYuAQO6AalaFABEVE3UAA)